# How can I say "undo" in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request, verbs

The question of how to express my username, Undo, in Latin recently came up [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27882791#27882791). As Ben Kovitz notes, Latin seems to lack the word 'defacio' or similar.

How can I say my name, the verb "undo", in Latin?

Comment: Well, the reason the the word défació doesn't exist in Latin is that, as in many verbs with prefixes, the vowel changes, and défació becomes défició. I'm not an expert on these vowel changes, so I can't usefully opine on them, but perhaps somebody else can.

That said, however, it's not clear to me that "undo" is a recognized meaning of défició. So I don't actually know the answer to your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use **[retexo](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=retexo&filter=CUTF8)**, literally "unweave, unravel", but also used to mean the below:

> B. Trop., *to break up, cancel, annul, reverse*

It depends a little bit on the context, though, what the best translation would be. Other candidates are *restituo, resolvo, abrogo, rescindo, induco, evacuo, exinanio, eludo, libero...*

Adjectives with a similar meaning include *infectus, irritus*...

Comment: Oooh, I vote for retexo, since its literal meaning is "unweave."

Comment: Nice list. Another possibility is "abrogo." Beyond the dictionary usages, I've heard "Scholae abrogatae sunt" (e.g. on a snow day).

Comment: @fvogel: Excellent, I've added it.